# Shutdown Startup Application

Tags: shutdown, startup, autostart, startup-applications, execute-command

In Ubuntu 16.04 after setting `shutdown now` as an automatic command to be executed at startup, is there a way to remove it again?

Comment: Do you boot to login screen or straight into Ubuntu with no login?

Comment: Where did you set the command ? In the GUI app called Startup Applications or  elsewhere ? `shutdown` command requires `sudo` , so if you set it in `Startup Applications` it would only run if you log-in, and requires `sudo` , so it wouldn't even run. Please clarify how you set up the command to run automatically; solution depends on the method you used.